# Increasing disk space

Tags: virtualization, fdisk

I just created a new Ubuntu VM on 18.10. I started it with a 1TB hard drive and went back in after install, and increased the size of the hard drive in VMWare to 2TB. However, when I run `fdisk`, this is what I see:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: I guess maybe to simplify my question, I need to convert the unused space under /dev/sda3 to be mounted under /.

Comment: Use live disk and run gparted to change sda3 size